# iOS/Cocoa: UIAlertView throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocoa

Seems like a shockingly trivial difference. Passing a non-`nil` value for `otherButtonTitles` to `UIAlerView` blows up.

Working:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Login with your credentials"
                      message:nil
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Not working:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Login with your credentials"
                      message:nil
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK"];
```

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Login with your credentials"
                      message:nil
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK1",@"OK2",nil];
```

Last argument is a multiple argument, should be terminated by nil.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should have this instead:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Login with your credentials"
                      message:nil
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```

Its stated [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/initWithTitle%3amessage%3adelegate%3acancelButtonTitle%3aotherButtonTitles%3a) that "Titles of additional buttons to add to the receiver, terminated with nil."

Basically, its a multi-value parameter that grabs values until the nil. Its the same way that arrays and lists work.